idenitfy rowTag elements from a huge xml
I have a huge XML file of 20k lines, before I process the data, I need to convert the data to a CSV file using Databricks (Python / Spark).
In this huge XML file, how to list all the 'rowTag' elements? Is there a way to find out??
Mean while I tried below:
For a simple xml, i can use below code to get CSV from a xml file.
data = "/FileStore/tables/Books.xml" 
df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","book").load(data)   
df.withColumnRenamed("id1","id").write.format("csv").option("header","true").save("/FileStore/tables/csv/")

For a huge xml , the challenge is, to identify the "rowTag" elements, which are in hundreds actually.. Is there a way to get them by running a script?
Sample xml shared below:
Update: Here scope is one major element in the xml. And PremInfo element has thousands of inner elements from the xml file.


What do you define as a rowTag? XML can deeply nested structures. How looks your xml structures?

my xml file is valid, but not able to decide on the rowTag, hence I need to list down all the rowTags. Final idea is to convert xml data to csv file.

My requirement is simple, I just want to convert the given huge xml to csv file.

Questions must provide a [mcve]. A representative sample of the xml structure should be added.

Hi RK. Share a valid sample of you xml and explain what you need based on this sample.

Sorry for the trouble, re-created sample xml file and attached above. Hope this helps. And my requirement is to convert this XML file CSV file, so that i can process the data later.

RK. XML should be shared as text and not as an image.

Got it, since i should not share it, hence sample screenshot attached.

It would be better, if i can get all the nested xml rowTag elements dynamically using any python or spark script?
