how to list down all rowTags from a large xml file
I have multiple xml files which are greater than 1 GB in size. Before I want to process the data, I need to list down all the rowTag elements from the xml using Python or PySpark.
As per the below sample xml file, book1 and book2 are rowTags here, in the similar way can I get all rowTags from a large xml file thru automated way?
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book1 id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book1>
   <book2 id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book2>
</catalog>

Update:
From a simple xml by using below code, I can read the data under the mentioned rowTag, but in a huge xml i may have thousands of rowtags, so how to identify the rowTags dynamics before I process the data?
df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","book1").load("books-1.xml")


What specific problem are you facing? What have you tried so far?

Shared update from my end shared. I need to list down all the rowTags before I read the xml data and process further.

The question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78314350/407651

Ok, can i achieve this? getting all rowTags in a automated way
